# what's the issue with this function passed as an argument?

Tags: javascript

```
var getarticles = function(subject){
      console.log("found your articles about: " + subject);   
}


var rl = rl || {};
rl.utils = (function () {
    var callApadter = function(adapter){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("inside the first timeout");
            adapter
        }, 4000);

    };
    return{
        callApadter: callApadter
    }})();


rl.utils.callApadter(getarticles("JS"));

 setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("this is 4 seconds");
       }, 4000);
```

Can anyone tell me why getarticles gets called immediately?

thanks guys.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UkAeV/

Comment: Because you *are* calling it immediately (`getarticles("JS")`). Putting `()` behind a function reference calls the function. Simple example: `foo(bar())`. `bar` is executed first and its return value is then passed to `foo`. It's not really surprising. OTOH, with  `foo(bar)`, `bar` itself is a passed to `foo` as argument.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Why would you make it into a variable instead of a function on it's own ?

Comment: You're calling the function here `getarticles("JS")`, not passing it as a callback. `adapter` does nothing anyway, it should be `adapter()`

Answer (score 1):

You are executing `getarticles` and pass the return value to `rl.utils.callApadter`.

However if you pass only the reference to `rl.utils.callApadter` it will work: <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9XKK/)</kbd>

```
var getarticles = function (subject) {
    alert("found your articles about: " + subject);
};


var rl = rl || {};
rl.utils = (function () {
    var callApadter = function (adapter) {
        var _this = this,
            _arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("inside the first timeout");
            adapter.apply(_this, _arguments);
        }, 4000);

    };
    return {
        callApadter: callApadter
    };
})();


rl.utils.callApadter(getarticles, "JS");

setTimeout(function () {
    alert("this is 3 seconds");
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually being called on line 20, rather than being passed:

```
rl.utils.callApadter(getarticles("JS"));
```

I think you want to do something like

```
rl.utils.callApadter(getarticles, "JS");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getarticles = function(subject){
    return function(){
        console.log("found your articles about: " + subject); 
    }  
}
```